# Docker permissions with Symfony 3

Tags: symfony, docker

There is problem with symfony cache and logs in docker containers.
Web server executes from www-data user and group and when I do symfony cache clear from docker container using php that is installed on docker, it executes from root.

So if I remove var/logs/dev.log for example and open url in browser, new log.dev gets created with user and group: www-data:www-data, but after i do cache clear, it gets permissions root:root and url in browser gives error dev.log permission denied.

I am not sure whats the problem, but I guess somehow nginx operates under www-data and when I execute console commands they operate from root user.

I have 4 containers: nginx, php-fpm, mysql, rabbit.

I also use version 3 of docker compose, I thought of solution with group_add but its no longer available in version 3

How do I configure this?

=================

docker-compose is similar to this:

```
version: "3"

services:
    nginx:
    image: nginx:1.11
    depends_on:
        - php-fpm
    links:
        - php-fpm
    environment:
        - NGINX_PORT=80
        - FASTCGI_HOST=php
        - FASTCGI_PORT=9000
        - DOCUMENT_ROOT=/usr/local/src/test-project/public
    ports:
        - 8095:80
    volumes:
        - .:/usr/local/src/test-project
        - ./docker/nginx/templates/default.conf.template:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf.template
        - ./docker/nginx/entrypoint.sh:/entrypoint.sh
    command: "/bin/bash /entrypoint.sh"

php-fpm:
    build: docker/php
    depends_on:
        - db
    extra_hosts:
        - "test-project:127.0.0.1"
    environment:
        DATABASE_URL: pgsql://test-project_users:test-project_users@db:5432/test-project_users
        APP_URL: 172.19.0.1:8095/
    working_dir: /usr/local/src/test-project
    volumes:
        - .:/usr/local/src/test-project

db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
        - '5599:5432'
    environment:
        POSTGRES_DB: test-project_users
        POSTGRES_USER: test-project_users
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: test-project_users
    volumes:
      - data:/var/lib/db
```

Comment: It would help to have your `docker-compose.yml`, e.g. are you using some volume or not ?

Comment: i don't have it with me now, but yes, they share same volume

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you are clearing the cache as root user via command-line. you should run the clear statement with su www-data.